# How to pass a database connection into Airflow KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, airflow

I'm having a confusion with `KubernetesPodOperator` from `Airflow`, and I'm wondering how to pass the `load_users_into_table()` function that it has a `conn_id` parameter stored in `connection` of `Airflow` in the Pod ?

In the official doc proposes to put the `conn_id`  in `Secret` but I don't understand how can I pass it in my function `load_users_into_table()` after that.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/kubernetes.html

**the function (task) to be executed in the pod:**

```
def load_users_into_table(postgres_hook, schema, path):
  gdf = read_csv(path)
  gdf.to_sql('users', con=postgres_hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine(), schema=schema)
```

**the dag:**

```
_pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id = _conn_id)

with dag: 
test = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace=namespace,
        image=image_name,
        cmds=["python", "-c"],
        arguments=[load_users_into_table],
        labels={"dag-id": dag.dag_id},
        name="airflow-test-pod",
        task_id="task-1",
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        in_cluster=in_cluster,
        get_logs=True,
        config_file=config_file,
        executor_config={
            "KubernetesExecutor": {"request_memory": "512Mi",
                                   "limit_memory": "1024Mi",
                                   "request_cpu": "1",
                                   "limit_cpu": "2"}
        }
    )
```

Comment: KubernetesPodOperator will run what inside image. I think you have two choices.


1. implement `load_users_into_table` and build docker image then you run it with KubernetesPodOperator


2. run the code with PythonOperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to run with K8sPodOperator, you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and add arguments to the docker cmd. Something in these lines should do the job:

```
import argparse
    

def f(arg):
    print(arg)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help')
args = parser.parse_args()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f(args.foo)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY main.py main.py
CMD ["python", "main.py", "--foo", "somebar"]
```

There are other ways to solve this such as using secrets, configMaps or even Airflow Variables, but this should get you moving forward.